# export datagridview data to csv file using c#

Tags: c#

I can export datagriview to csv but exporting one line data and
nextline empty line is creating
without empty line it should export to csv file
how to remove empty line

```
internal void ExtractDataToCSV(DataGridView dgv)
{
    try
    {
            var fDialog = new SaveFileDialog();
            fDialog.Filter = "csv Files (*.csv,*.csv)|*.csv;*.csv";
            if (fDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(fDialog.FileName))
            {
                StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fDialog.FileName);
                for (int i = 0; i < dgv.Columns.Count; i++)
                {
                    sw.Write(dgv.Columns[i].HeaderText);
                    sw.Write(",");
                }
                sw.Write(sw.NewLine);
                foreach (DataGridViewRow dr in dgv.Rows)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < dgv.Columns.Count; i++)
                    {
                        sw.Write(dr.Cells[i].Value);
                        sw.Write(",");
                    }
                    sw.Write(sw.NewLine);
                }
                sw.Close();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
}

private void BtnUserInfo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    ObjCsvFileIO = new CsvFileIO();
    dgv.DataSource = ObjCsvFileIO.ReadCsvFile(string CSVFilePathName);

 }
```

Output
[image: output]

Expected output
[image: Expected output]

Comment: have you tried getting rid of the sw.Write(sw.NewLine); lines?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Could you please formulate your question properly? <3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove marked lines. This code generating extra blank row for you.

[image]